# jquery function if param exist in url

Tags: jquery, url, substring

Hello i have this code:

```
if ($('.page-id-6 #cherry-posts-list-1 .item-2 .post-title a').text().length > 28);
{
    $('.page-id-6 #cherry-posts-list-1 .item-2 .post-title a').text( $('.page-id-6 #cherry-posts-list-1 .item-2 .post-title a').text().substring(0,28));
}
```

it run good but i need also to set substring at 35 only if in url there is: "/en/".

28 default, 35 only if "/en/" is present in url.

Can help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.prototype.indexOf` method for checking the existence of the segment:

```
$('.page-id-6 #cherry-posts-list-1 .item-2 .post-title a').text(function(_, text) {
   var len = this.getAttribute('href').indexOf('/en/') > -1 ? 35 : 28;
   // the subsequent lines can be replaced with `return text.substring(0, len);`
   if ( text.length > len ) {
     return text.substring(0, len);
   }
   return text;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to check the URL with Javascript

```
 if (window.location.href.indexOf("/en/") > -1) {
      // do stuff
 }
```